# How to print required fields

Tags: bash, awk

Input lines:

```
a b=34 c d="12 34 54" e f=387
a b=12 c z d="89 08 23" e f=321 g=12
```

I want to print two fields b and d.
Ouptut required is like:

```
b=34 d="12 34 54"
b=12 d="89 08 23"
```

I tried like

```
awk '{print $2, $4}' filename
```

but this is not producing correct output.

Comment: I tried using awk, but not succeeded, which is ignoring quotes and printing like   b=34 d="12.

Comment: Edit your question with how you trying

Comment: @user2402905 : Please clarify: Is the value of the fields always either a number, or a space-separated list of numbers enclosed in double-quotes?

Answer (score 2):

This `sed` should work here:

```
sed -E -n 's/[^b]*(b=[0-9]+) [^d]*(d=".*") [^bd]*/\1 \2/p' file_name
```

Output:

```
b=34 d="12 34 54"
b=12 d="89 08 23"
```

Answer (score 2):

If `gawk` 4.0 or newer is available, how about utilizing `FPAT`?
Please try:

```
gawk -v FPAT='[^ ]+|\\w+="[^"]+"' '
    {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if (match($i, "^(b|d)")) printf("%s ", $i); print ""}
' input.txt
```

The output:

```
b=34 d="12 34 54" 
b=12 d="89 08 23"
```

`FPAT`, an `awk` variable, is a regular expression to match the contents of each field, instead of splitting the line with a field separator.

Answer (score 0):

Awk out of the box does not parse quoted fields. If you want to extract quoted fields with Awk, you need to implement parsing of quoted fields.

The shell, out of the box, parses these just fine; but you probably want to avoid parsing user input as code.

If you can trust the input (i.e. it comes from a configuration file you have complete control over) then something like

```
string='a b=34 c d="12 34 54" e f=387'
eval "$string"
```

will set all the variables in there to their expected values.

Perhaps you would like to parse the string yourself, though. Try this:

```
grepvar () {
    grep -Po "$1"'=\K([^"]+|"[^"]*")'
}
a=$(grepvar "a" filename)
b=$(grepvar "b" <<<"$string")
```

If you don't have `grep -P` (which is a GNU extension) there are easy workarounds; but you don't tell us much about your requirements and there are many near-duplicates of this question, so it should not be hard to find something which works for you.

If you just want to print the extracted values and not do anything with the actual values

```
grep -Eo 'a=([^"]+|"[^"]*")' filename
grep -Eo 'b=([^"]+|"[^"]*")' <<<"$string"
```

The above shows both how to read from a file named `filename` and how to parse a variable `$string` which already contains the text.  The `<<<` "here string" is a Bash extension which will not work e.g. with `sh`.

Comment: This is one of the rare times I actually like the use of an `eval`. :)